# Android Webview - detect jquery document ready

Tags: javascript, java, android, jquery, webview

I use an Android Webview to convert a website to an android app. The website uses many JavaScript files and many of them start at $(document).ready(). The website works great, but the app recognizes only the $(document).ready() from the first file. "console.log("anything");" placed on second file run only if it is outside of $(document).ready().

Answer (score 0):

// Java

```
private void javaRun(String script)
    {

        if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            myWebView.evaluateJavascript(script, null);
        } else {
            myWebView.loadUrl(script);
        }
    }

@Override
            public void onPageFinished(final WebView view, String url) {

                super.onPageFinished(view, url);

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            javaRun("javascript:ready();");


                        }
                    }, 200);


            }
```

// Javascript

```
function ready()
{

$('li').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('read');

});

}
```